# JSOn parse in Android

Tags: android, json

I want to parse this JSON file in Android.

```
{
    "problems": {
        "1": {
            "Answer": "D"
        },
        "2": {
            "Answer": "A"
        },
        "3": {
            "Answer": "D"
        },
        "4": {
            "Answer": "A"
        },
....
...

.....
  "153": {
            "Answer": "E"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to insert each answer with number in sqlitedatabase.

I have tried this:

```
   JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(text);
      JSONObject jObjectResult = jObject.getJSONObject("problems");
   JSONObject jArray = jObjectResult.getJSONObject("1");


      System.out.println("Jarray---->"+jArray);
     String answer = "";


     for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                       answer = jObjectResult.getJSONObject("2").toString();

                        System.out.println("Answer---->"+answer);

                  }
```

But I am getting only one value. I am not getting how to handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON feed you have does not have an array.
All the nodes -> "1", "2", "3"..."153" are objects and do not form an array.
You may try something like this.

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(your_json_text);
JSONObject jObjectResult = jObject.getJSONObject("problems");
for(int i=1; i<=153; i++) {
    JSONObject innerObject = jObjectResult.getJSONObject(""+i);
    String answer = innerObject.getString("Answer");
    System.out.println("Answer---->"+answer);
}
```

Hopefully this will work

Answer (score 2):

First change your json Response so it will be easy to parse it.like this way

```
 {
"problems": [
    {
        "Question":"1",
        "Answer": "D"
    },
    {
     "Question":"2",
        "Answer": "A"
    },
    {
         "Question":"3",
        "Answer": "D"
    },
     {
        "Question":"4",
        "Answer": "A"
    },
  ....
  ...

  .....
 {
        "Question":"153",
        "Answer": "E"
    }
  ]
```

and now parse this response

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(text);
  JSONObject jObjectResultArray = jObject.getJSONArray("problems");

    for (int i = 0; i < jObjectResultArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject objresult = jObjectResultArray
                        .getJSONObject(i);

                        System.out.println("Question---->"+objresult.getString("Question"));)
                        System.out.println("Answer---->"+objresult.getString("Answer")););


            }
```

Comment: Sorry I cant change json file its from client :) and working on iphone.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON model has no arrays at all.  In JSON, an array is specified with square brackets `[]`

Here, you have an Object, which has a "problems" property, which has properties "1", "2", "3", etc.  Your root object also has a "153" property, which has properties "1", "2", "3", etc.  Each of those 1, 2, 3 names correspond to objects which have a single "Answer" property with a string value.

You could use JSONObject.names() to get a JSONArray and iterate through that at the "problems" and "153" level.

You should learn to read and write JSON before trying to parse it.

If your json is basically static I would suggest using a better JSON library like [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) and [create a java model](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes#Full_Data_Binding_.28POJO.29_Example) rather than writing painful code to walk the structure every time.